# How can I get reference to none static variables and use them inside static methods?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Or maybe to make the variables static and get reference to them in the editor.
This script sit in my Game scene.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SceneFader : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region FIELDS
    public GameObject fadeOutUIGameobjectImage;
    public float fadeSpeed = 0.8f;
    public bool loaded = false;

    private static Image fadeOutUIImage;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }

    public enum FadeDirection
    {
        In, //Alpha = 1
        Out // Alpha = 0
    }
    #endregion

    #region FADE
    public static IEnumerator Fade(FadeDirection fadeDirection)
    {
        fadeOutUIGameobjectImage.SetActive(true);

        float alpha = (fadeDirection == FadeDirection.Out) ? 1 : 0;
        float fadeEndValue = (fadeDirection == FadeDirection.Out) ? 0 : 1;
        if (fadeDirection == FadeDirection.Out)
        {
            while (alpha >= fadeEndValue)
            {
                SetColorImage(ref alpha, fadeDirection);
                yield return null;
            }
            fadeOutUIGameobjectImage.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            fadeOutUIGameobjectImage.SetActive(true);
            while (alpha <= fadeEndValue)
            {
                SetColorImage(ref alpha, fadeDirection);
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region HELPERS
    public static IEnumerator FadeAndLoadSceneNewGame(FadeDirection fadeDirection, string sceneToLoad)
    {
        yield return Fade(fadeDirection);

        loaded = false;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneToLoad);   
    }

    public static IEnumerator FadeAndLoadSceneLoadGame(FadeDirection fadeDirection, string sceneToLoad)
    {
        yield return Fade(fadeDirection);

        loaded = true;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneToLoad);

        var saveLoad = GameObject.Find("Save System").GetComponent<SaveLoad>();
        saveLoad.Load();
    }

    private static void SetColorImage(ref float alpha, FadeDirection fadeDirection)
    {
        if(fadeOutUIImage == null)
        {
            fadeOutUIImage = fadeOutUIGameobjectImage.GetComponent<Image>();
        }

        fadeOutUIImage.color = new Color(fadeOutUIImage.color.r, fadeOutUIImage.color.g, fadeOutUIImage.color.b, alpha);
        alpha += Time.deltaTime * (1.0f / fadeSpeed) * ((fadeDirection == FadeDirection.Out) ? -1 : 1);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Now the variables in the tope are public but not static so I can't use them in the rest of the script and if I make them static I can't reference to them in the editor I tried to use Find in the Start when they are static but they are null.

And this script sit in my Main Menu scene I thought make the two methods in the Game scene public static will be easier to call them from the Main Menu scene :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEditor;
using Cinemachine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class MenuController : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Default Values
    [Header("Default Menu Values")]
    [SerializeField] private float defaultVolume;
    [SerializeField] private int defaultSen;
    [SerializeField] private bool defaultInvertY;

    [Header("Levels To Load")]
    public string _newGameButtonLevel;
    private string levelToLoad;
    public GameObject player;

    private int menuNumber;
    #endregion

    #region Menu Dialogs
    [Header("Main Menu Components")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject menuDefaultCanvas;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject GeneralSettingsCanvas;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject graphicsMenu;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject soundMenu;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject controlsMenu;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject confirmationMenu;
    [Space(10)]
    [Header("Menu Popout Dialogs")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject noSaveDialog;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject newGameDialog;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject loadGameDialog;
    #endregion

    #region Slider Linking
    [Header("Menu Sliders")]
    [SerializeField] private Text controllerSenText;
    [SerializeField] private Slider controllerSenSlider;
    public float controlSenFloat = 2f;
    [Space(10)]
    [SerializeField] private Text volumeText;
    [SerializeField] private Slider volumeSlider;
    [Space(10)]
    [SerializeField] private Toggle invertYToggle;
    #endregion

    #region Initialisation - Button Selection & Menu Order
    private void Start()
    {
        menuNumber = 1;
    }
    #endregion

    //MAIN SECTION
    public IEnumerator ConfirmationBox()
    {
        confirmationMenu.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        confirmationMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (menuNumber == 2 || menuNumber == 7 || menuNumber == 8)
            {
                GoBackToMainMenu();
                ClickSound();
            }

            else if (menuNumber == 3 || menuNumber == 4 || menuNumber == 5)
            {
                GoBackToOptionsMenu();
                ClickSound();
            }

            else if (menuNumber == 6) //CONTROLS MENU
            {
                ClickSound();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ClickSound()
    {
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }

    #region Menu Mouse Clicks
    public void MouseClick(string buttonType)
    {
        if (buttonType == "Controls")
        {
            controlsMenu.SetActive(true);
            menuNumber = 6;
        }

        if (buttonType == "Graphics")
        {
            GeneralSettingsCanvas.SetActive(false);
            graphicsMenu.SetActive(true);
            menuNumber = 3;
        }

        if (buttonType == "Sound")
        {
            GeneralSettingsCanvas.SetActive(false);
            soundMenu.SetActive(true);
            menuNumber = 4;
        }

        if (buttonType == "Exit")
        {
            Debug.Log("YES QUIT!");
            Application.Quit();
        }

        if (buttonType == "Options")
        {
            menuDefaultCanvas.SetActive(false);
            GeneralSettingsCanvas.SetActive(true);
            menuNumber = 2;
        }

        if (buttonType == "LoadGame")
        {
            menuDefaultCanvas.SetActive(false);
            loadGameDialog.SetActive(true);
            menuNumber = 8;
        }

        if (buttonType == "NewGame")
        {
            menuDefaultCanvas.SetActive(false);
            newGameDialog.SetActive(true);
            menuNumber = 7;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public void VolumeSlider(float volume)
    {
        AudioListener.volume = volume;
        volumeText.text = volume.ToString("0.0");
    }

    public void VolumeApply()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("masterVolume", AudioListener.volume);
        Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("masterVolume"));
        StartCoroutine(ConfirmationBox());
    }

    public void ControllerSen()
    {
        controllerSenText.text = controllerSenSlider.value.ToString("0");
        controlSenFloat = controllerSenSlider.value;
    }

    #region ResetButton
    public void ResetButton(string GraphicsMenu)
    {
        if (GraphicsMenu == "Audio")
        {
            AudioListener.volume = defaultVolume;
            volumeSlider.value = defaultVolume;
            volumeText.text = defaultVolume.ToString("0.0");
            VolumeApply();
        }

        if (GraphicsMenu == "Graphics")
        {
            controllerSenText.text = defaultSen.ToString("0");
            controllerSenSlider.value = defaultSen;
            controlSenFloat = defaultSen;

            invertYToggle.isOn = false;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Dialog Options - This is where we load what has been saved in player prefs!
    public void ClickNewGameDialog(string ButtonType)
    {
        if (ButtonType == "Yes")
        {
            newGameDialog.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(SceneFader.FadeAndLoadSceneNewGame(SceneFader.FadeDirection.In, _newGameButtonLevel));
        }

        if (ButtonType == "No")
        {
            GoBackToMainMenu();
        }
    }

    public void ClickLoadGameDialog(string ButtonType)
    {
        if (ButtonType == "Yes")
        {
            newGameDialog.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(SceneFader.FadeAndLoadSceneLoadGame(SceneFader.FadeDirection.In, _newGameButtonLevel)); 
        }

        if (ButtonType == "No")
        {
            GoBackToMainMenu();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Back to Menus
    public void GoBackToOptionsMenu()
    {
        GeneralSettingsCanvas.SetActive(true);
        graphicsMenu.SetActive(false);
        soundMenu.SetActive(false);

        VolumeApply();

        menuNumber = 2;
    }

    public void GoBackToMainMenu()
    {
        menuDefaultCanvas.SetActive(true);
        newGameDialog.SetActive(false);
        loadGameDialog.SetActive(false);
        noSaveDialog.SetActive(false);
        GeneralSettingsCanvas.SetActive(false);
        graphicsMenu.SetActive(false);
        soundMenu.SetActive(false);
        menuNumber = 1;
    }

    public void ClickQuitOptions()
    {
        GoBackToMainMenu();
    }

    public void ClickNoSaveDialog()
    {
        GoBackToMainMenu();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In this script I have two events :

ClickNewGameDialog and ClickLoadGameDialog that I'm calling them from OnClick buttons in the main menu.

I created this script and added it to an empty GameObject in the Game scene :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class NewGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here you store the actual instance
    private static NewGame _instance;

    // Public read-only access property
    public static NewGame Instance
    {
        get
        {
            // if already set simply return directly
            if (_instance) return _instance;

            // Otherwise try to find it in the scene
            _instance = FindObjectOfType<NewGame>();
            if (_instance) return _instance;

            // Otherwise create it now
            _instance = new GameObject(nameof(NewGame)).AddComponent<NewGame>();

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private bool _gameStarted;
    public static bool GameStarted => Instance._gameStarted;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance && _instance != this)
        {
            // There already exist another instance 
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise this is the active instance and should not be destroyed
        _instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);

        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;

        // update it once now 
        _gameStarted = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex != 0;
    }

    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        _gameStarted = scene.buildIndex != 0;
    }
}
```

but when I tried to use it for exmaple in the Game scene like this :

```
if(NewGame.GameStarted != true)
```

GameStarted is all the time true never false so it's all the time staring a new game even if the player clicked the Load Game button.

Comment: Then why did you make the methods `static` if you want to access instance variables?

Comment: @UnholySheep because this methods are in my Game scene and I want to access the methods from my Main Menu scene two methods that I'm calling from new game button and load game button.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you made them static, you could easily access an instance of your class, either by making those buttons have a reference to it, or by fetching it at runtime (via a `GetComponent` call)

Comment: @UnholySheep Updated my question with the script and two buttons events in my Main Menu scene can you show me how can I reference the methods in the Game scene ? I want to be able to know in any script/s in the Game scene if the player clicked the New Game button or the Load Game button. and I'm not sure if using just a public static bool in the main menu script is good idea.

Comment: @UnholySheep Before I used a public static bool flag in the MenuController script and set it to true or false depending on the button the user clicked new game or load game. but I think the public static bool did problems when I used in the Game scene script/s that's why I'm trying to find what button the player clicked in other way/s.

Comment: You probably want to have a manager class that is either a `static class` or is attached to an object marked with `Object.DontDestroyOnLoad`: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html. Putting `static` fields into `MonoBehaviour` derived classes will not play nicely with how Unity handles such classes during scene changes

Comment: @UnholySheep You right, I updated my question last time edited with a script using DontDestroyOnLoad tried to make it and use it but without success. Can you take a look and see what did I do wrong and what should I do with it in the main menu scene ? The script is attached to empty GameObject in the Game scene. The idea was to use something like if(NewGame.GameStarted != true) or if(NewGame.GameStarted == true) to check if the player clicked on new game button or load game button. and use it in script/s in the Game scene.

Answer (score 0):

Use Singletone Design Pattern. Create a static variable that refers to your script like this:

```
public static YourCodeBehaviour Instance;
```

Then in Awake method you just check if it null and set it if true, like this.

```
private void Awake() {
    if(Instance == null)
        Instance = this;
    else {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Then you got an Instance that you can access from your static methods, cause Instance is static and got the actual alive instance.

Good luck!